# The dollar ($) prefixed field '$oid' in 'features.0._id.$oid' is not valid for storage

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoid

I have the following Mongo collection attached below.
it is existing one not new collection created, I am trying to push new item in the features array, but I am not able to achieve that due to the following error: **The dollar ($) prefixed field '$oid' in 'features.0._id.$oid' is not valid for storage.**
using this script:

```
db.getCollection("test").update({ _id: "RYB0001" },
{
  $push: {
    "features": {
      "_id": {
          "$oid": ObjectId(),
      },
      "featureItems": [],
      "typeId": "type3"
    }
   }
});
```

If it is a driver version issue, any workaround can I do to push the new item to the current collection?
MongoDb version: 4.0.4
[Mongo Collection screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjQOh.png)

Comment: Please don't paste images for documents, use formatted text.

Comment: Field names (`$oid`) in MongoDB must not start with a dollar sign. Try `oid`. 

See [Restrictions on Field Names](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/index.html#Restrictions-on-Field-Names)

Comment: How about just `"_id": ObjectId()` ? Why do you still need the `$oid` encoding syntax if you are putting in the objectid object already?

Comment: @WerfriedDomscheit, Currently the collection has data in that format and just needs to push a new item in the feature array. have this $oid like the one in the screenshot, I tried to use **oid: ObjectId**  but still getting the same error.

Comment: @Thilo. I tried that but still getting the same error. My current collection has data like the sample collection in the screenshot and not able to push new item in that array.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, [https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-41628?fbclid=IwAR1t5Ld58LwCi69SrMCcDbhPGf2EfBWe_AEurxGkEWHpZTHaEIde0_AZ-uM] Based on the link here Starting from MongoDB 3.6 it is not supported. but how to update current existing DB?

Comment: If current data have `$oid` then I would strongly recommend to migrate your data to use a field without $ - you will save a lot of problems.

Answer (score 2):

The $oid notation is part of [MongoDB's Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#bson.ObjectId). I assume the data in your database doesn't actually have that key-value pair and it was only represented that way after using something like `JSON.stringify(obj)`

```
> db.test.find({});
{ "_id" : "RYB0001", "features" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("5e40d46a97abdef3faa0d5d9"), "featureItems" : [ ], "typeId" : "type3" } ] }
> JSON.stringify(db.test.find({})[0]);
{"_id":"RYB0001","features":[{"_id":{"$oid":"5e40d46a97abdef3faa0d5d9"},"featureItems":[],"typeId":"type3"}]}
```

You'll need to generate a new ObjectId using its constructor `"_id": new ObjectId()`, note the `new` keyword there, I think @Thilo may have missed that in their comment.

```
db.getCollection("test").update({ _id: "RYB0001" },
{
  $push: {
    "features": {
      "_id": new ObjectId(),
      "featureItems": [],
      "typeId": "type3"
    }
   }
});
```